# templated user-defined conversion function and std::optional

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++20

Is there a way for a templated user-defined conversion function to correctly detect the output type as `std::optional`?

I have the following code:

```
template<typename T>
struct conv_impl final{
    explicit conv_impl(const T& t): t_(t) {}

    template<typename U>
    explicit(false) operator U() const { return U{}; }

private:
    const T& t_;
};
```

and then use it as follow

```
double a = conv_impl{int32_t{5}};
std::optional<double> d  = conv_impl{double(5)};
```

but `U` is never *detected* as `std::optional`.

The idea would be to put a `if constexpr (is_optional<U>)` in the body (along with other logic for the actual conversion)

The following example shows the problem: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fqWhqanaq).

(edit)Additional Information:

1. This is a minimal working example that shows my problem exactly without complicating the example with a proper implementation nor constraints.
2. This is not production code, but based on a much larger implementation, which should become production code (trying something but this problem is tripping me up)
3. The actual implementation is constrained with a few concepts, based on custom conversion functions that must be defined.
4. This question arises from the need to handle `std::optional` in a different way (Already custom for `std::vector`)
5. Since a few people commented on the minimal example and simplicity of the solution, here is more complete example: https://godbolt.org/z/zGEq36TPn
6. In contrast to the example code, `conv_impl` will never be constructed with a `std::optional`, there is other logic that determines how the conversion to `std::optional` will behave.
7. The code tries to improve maintenance and debugging converting from external, c++11 structures to new internal structures.

Comment: whats the aim? `conv_impl` always has a `T` to return, it never needs the `nullopt`, hence converting to `T` (and then allowing the caller to convert to a `std::optional`) seems to be just fine

Comment: This looks like a defect in `std::optional` to me. They have quite a greedy templated constructor that accepts anything convertible to `T`, even if it's also convertible to `std::optional<T>`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, as a follow-up: If I read cppreference correctly, the templated ctor (8) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) and templated assignment operatior (4) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator%3D) are conditionally explicit and just not as greedy as you claim (but I am not sure I understand this fully). I think the main problem is that the conversion operator of `conv_impl` is too generic https://godbolt.org/z/qv79esEaW.

Comment: @joergbrech Mhm, I didn't spell out all the SFINAE conditions of that `optional` constructor, but I still believe that it should also reject types convertible to `optional<T>`. What OP does looks like a common pattern to me, one would expect that that constructing any type (perhaps other than `std::any`) from `conv_impl` would call the conversion operator to that type.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I agree that one would expect the code to work. I am still trying to figure out the problem. Note that if my comment above was correct, then `std::optional<asdf> h  = conv_impl{double(5)};` should perform the proper conversion, because `asdf` is neither scalar nor `conv_impl<double>`. But it doesn't: https://godbolt.org/z/eG5594sq9

Comment: @joergbrech `conv_impl` satisfies the conditions for constructor (8), I believe? And that constructor converts whatever was passed to it to `T` rather than `optional<T>`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah I see. Thanks for the clarification. So I suppose I agree that this is a defect :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the inputs so far, a more representative example is: https://godbolt.org/z/zGEq36TPn

Comment: The user-defined conversion function is completely foreign to `conv_impl`. It could be a free function since it doesn't actually need a `conv_impl<T>` (i.e. it works in "standalone" with it's own `U`). As for `std::optional<double> d  = conv_impl{double(5)};`, if working, would hold a default constructed `double` (from the `return U{};` statement), so this whole instruction seems useless to me, the `double(5)` won't be used at all and will be destroyed since it's a member of a temporary `conv_impl<double>`.

Comment: Isn't the issue more general? At least, for me, it's unclear how the compiler will chose the appropriate conversion function in assignment-like expressions ```lhs = rhs```. lhs object can accept a set of rhs types for its initialization/affectation. rhs object can produce, from conversion, a different set of objects types. If both set are disjoint, it's an error, if not what are the rules to chose the intermediate type? Is there not a possibility for ambiguity?

Comment: @Oersted, "what are the rules to choose the intermediate type": Just like overload resolution, candidate conversion sequences are ranked and the highest ranking candidate wins. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences. If there is ambiguity after the ranking, it's en error.

Comment: thanks for the link but in this case, should we follow the ranking, considering that lhs is ```std::optional<double>``` or should we consider that ```d``` can be constructed from a ```double``` or another ```optional```. In this case why chose the conversion to ```double``` instead of conversion to ```optional``` (it would seem that the later implies one conversion less)?

Comment: @Oersted: in fact, it is constructor (`std::optional<double>(conv_impl <double>&&)`) vs convertion `conv_impl <double>::operator(std::optional<double>)`. (then constructor do a conversion to `double`).

Comment: @Jarod2 It's what I meant in my previous comment. It seems that it can be chosen between constructor and conversion. But in this case what selection rule kicks in?

Comment: I tried a [toy case](https://godbolt.org/z/1hfj7eMPa) but obtain a different result from OP: conversion is always chosen. The final copy or move construction is elided.